# Angular2 Observable not rendering until data changed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2, so hopefully I have an easy problem to solve :)

I am trying to share data (a list of objects, locally stored in memory by service) across multiple views (that are separate routes) using an observable service. The problem is that when I change route (i.e. through a link), the shared data does not render until I "add" a new item to the list (i.e. in current route). I've seen many *similar* issues on stack overflow but none of the solutions have quite worked.

I don't know if the error is in my routing, my ngInit function (i.e. rendering before data is complete?) or in the way I've defined the service/component themselves. Here are some code snippets to illustrate:

**Routing:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/running-order',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'running-order',
    component: RunningOrderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'enquiry',
    component: EnquiryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'config',
    component: ConfigComponent
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ChaptersService{

    //Observable Source
    private chaptersSource:Subject<BaseChapter[]>;

    //Observable Stream
    chapters$: Observable<BaseChapter[]>;

    //DataStore
    private dataStore:{ chapters: BaseChapter[] };

    constructor() {
        console.log('chapter service instantiated');
        this.chaptersSource = new Subject<BaseChapter[]>();
        this.chapters$ = this.chaptersSource.asObservable();
        this.dataStore = { chapters: [] };      
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.chaptersSource.next(this.dataStore.chapters);
    }

    addChapter(data:BaseChapter){
        this.dataStore.chapters.push(data);
        this.chaptersSource.next(this.dataStore.chapters);
    }
}
```

**Component (Routed):**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'myenquiry',
    templateUrl: 'enquiry.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['enquiry.component.css']
})

export class EnquiryComponent implements OnInit{
    config : Config;
    title = 'Enquiry Angular App';
    selectedChapter: BaseChapter;

    chapters$: Observable<BaseChapter[]>;

    constructor(private chaptersService:ChaptersService){}

    ngOnInit():void {
        this.chaptersService.loadAll();
        this.chapters$ = this.chaptersService.chapters$;
        console.log('enquiry component initialised...');
    }

    onSelect(chapter: BaseChapter): void {
      this.selectedChapter = chapter;
    }

    addChapter():void {
        var chapter:Chapter = new Chapter(0);
        chapter.initChapter("untitled",4);
        this.chaptersService.addChapter(chapter);
        this.selectedChapter = chapter;
    }
}
```

**Component Template:**

```
<h2>List of Chapters</h2>
<ul class="chapters">
    <li *ngFor="let chapter of chapters$ | async" [class.selected]="chapter === selectedChapter" (click)="onSelect(chapter)" >
        <span class="idStyle">{{chapter.id}}</span> {{chapter.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<chapter [chapterData]="selectedChapter"></chapter>
<button (click)="addChapter()">Add Chapter</button>
```

thanks, Phil.

Comment: Try using `BehaviorSubject`, it has default value you can specify.

Comment: @Sasxa it's not that i need a default to appear, i mean that nothing appears even if there is data until adding another item. i.e. every time you return to the route, it's blank until you add another item, then all the items show up...

Comment: Change private chaptersSource:Subject<BaseChapter[]>;
to be a replaysubject, that way if the observable gets a value BEFORE your component has bound it will get the last value pushed still.

Comment: @PaulSwetz That looks like that has worked! If you want to make your comment into an answer I'll upvote/mark as solution?

Comment: done, thanks for the votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
private chaptersSource:Subject<BaseChapter[]>;
```

to be

```
private chaptersSource:ReplaySubject<BaseChapter[]>;
```

that way if the observable gets a value BEFORE your component has bound it will get the last value pushed still.